# Installshield event ordering

Tags: installshield

I have a custom setup dialog, which allows the user to select features.

Let's call them:

- Feature A
- Feature B

Once the user clicks the next button, a new dialog will open depending on what was selected.

My events look like this:

```
> New Dialog -> &FeatureA = 3 -> DialogA 
> New Dialog -> &FeatureB = 3 -> DialogB
```

Obviously this is simplified, in reality there's OR clauses everywhere.

My question is why, even after changing the event order, only dialog B is ever opened, if both features are selected?

Comment: I'm not sure you can control in which order the conditions are evaluated in this case. why not use more specific condition e.g. "FeatureA=3 and featureB !=3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the second paragraph of [ControlEvent Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368037.aspx):

> The exception to note is that each control can publish a most one NewDialog or one SpawnDialog event. If you need to author multiple NewDialog and SpawnDialog control events in this table, also include conditional statements in the Condition fields that ensure at most one event is published. If multiple NewDialog and SpawnDialog control events are selected for the same control, only the event with the largest value in the Ordering column gets published when the control is activated.

You're best off giving mutually exclusive conditions to all NewDialog control events on a given control. Ordering them correctly should work, but this is easy to mess up.